# Why isn't this working on Internet Explorer? [jQuery, radio, selectors]

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to debug something that does not work on any version of Internet Explorer.

Here's the code :

```
<div id="sondage">
    <input type="radio" name="reponse" value="oui" id="oui">
    <label for="oui">Oui</label>

    <input type="radio" name="reponse" value="non" id="non">
    <label for="non">Non</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){

    $('#oui, #non').click(function(){
        reponse = $('input[name=reponse]:checked').val();
        sondage_id = <?php echo $sondage->id ?>;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo url_for('@sondage_repondre') ?>",
            data: "reponse="+reponse+"&id="+sondage_id,
            success: function(msg){
                resultat = msg.split('|');

                if (resultat[0] == "true") {
                    $('#sondage_message').html("<?php echo __('Merci.') ?>");
                } else {
                    $('#sondage_message').html("<?php echo __('Désolé, vous avez déjà voté pour ce sondage. Merci.') ?>");
                }
                $('#sondage').html(resultat[1]);
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

The error happens on that line (`reponse = $('input[name=reponse]:checked').val();`).

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thanks!

EDIT: As asked: the error is:

```
Line 511, Char 7, Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

And here's the complete output : http://pastie.org/1355610

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's causing the error? I don't trust IE's line numbers, but you could verify it by hardcoding that value, and see if it works. What error do you get? Could you please update your question with the rendered code ("view source") instead of the actual source? The `<? php echo`'s are not what IE is seeing, so that doesn't help us much. If `$sondage->id` yields a string, or an empty value, for instance, this will break on any browser.

Comment: You are totally right, I updated the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting from IE?

Comment: Line 511, Char 7, Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `var` in there, it should be:

```
var reponse = $('input[name=reponse]:checked').val();
```

The same goes for your other variables...always use `var` to declare them, no matter where they are, don't depend on a implicit global definition which isn't always allowed.

Comment: but it's perfectly valid to implicitly declare variables.  that should not cause the script to crap out.  Admittedly better coding practice to explicitly declare variables, however.

Comment: @Metagrapher - it's not *valid*, it's *allowed* in some cases. In both it's bad practice.

Comment: @Pointy: I had no idea! But it looks like you're right http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/677442.aspx

Comment: Totally right, damn it I almost never forget about that stuff... My bad. Thanks!